# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [create_node/turtlebot_node.py]: can't locate node [turtlebot_node.py] in package [create_node]

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am have installed turtlebot binaries. While executing :

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

I am getting error as :

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [create_node/turtlebot_node.py]: can't locate node [turtlebot_node.py] in package [create_node]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [create_node/kinect_breaker_enabler.py]: can't locate node [kinect_breaker_enabler.py] in package [create_node]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [create_node/load_calib.py]: can't locate node [load_calib.py] in package [create_node]
```

I have reinstalled turtlebot package more than thrice. I am still facing this issue.

I have create_node package installed. All the three files (`turtlebot_node.py,kinect_breaker_enabler.py,load_calib.py`) are present in `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/create_node folder`. When I move these files from `lib` folder to `share/create_node` I get below error:

```
[turtlebot_node-4] process has died [pid 5091, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/share/create_node/turtlebot_node.py --respawnable cmd_vel:=mobile_base/commands/velocity turtlebot_node/sensor_state:=mobile_base/sensors/core imu/data:=mobile_base/sensors/imu_data imu/raw:=mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw __name:=turtlebot_node __log:=/home/nvidia/.ros/log/ca2facc4-1432-11e8-91f4-00044b8c7fdc/turtlebot_node-4.log].
log file: /home/nvidia/.ros/log/ca2facc4-1432-11e8-91f4-00044b8c7fdc/turtlebot_node-4*.log
```

Any help with this issue is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283010/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bcreate_node/turtlebot_node.py%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Bturtlebot_node.py%5D-in-package-%5Bcreate_node%5D/) by [samiksha](https://answers.ros.org/users/33741/samiksha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You *should not* modify the `setup.bash` file. You need to source both of the `setup.bash` files of your distribution *and* your workspace. Please see [the tutorial on the creating a `catkin` workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samiksha](https://answers.ros.org/users/33741/samiksha/) on 2018-02-19**:
Okay. I have reverted the changes.